# Symfony2 + FOSUserBundle registration form not submitting, only reloading

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I've been at my wit's end for a few days now with this issue and I can't seem to find the problem.

Overview:

- I'm building a Symfony2 website using FOSUserBundle as the user
  manager, and Propel as the database provider.
- I've successfully overridden the login template and I can
  log in and out successfully from a modal view.
- I've added 6 custom fields to my schema.xml, and the model builds correctly (ie. I can query these fields in a tabulated User Manager).
- I can successfully register as a new user in the default route for registration on my overridden form, and the data shows up in my database as expected.

The Issue:

I have moved the registration form to its final position inside a modal view in my 'user manager dashboard'. My form loads and displays correctly, but for whatever reason refuses to submit data to the controller for processing. Instead it simply loads the default route for registration ('/register') and displays the form again but without any of my css, js, or base twig template. When I re-enter information in that form, it simply reloads with none of the info going in to the database.

I am convinced the issue lies in either (or both) how I am submitting the form or how I have classed the form.

Note I have changed the name of my classes to the statutory AcmeBundle for obvious reasons :)

Can anyone shed some light on this? I am literally about to implode over this issue!

Thank you in advance :D

**EDIT**

I now think this could possibly be a routing issue as I have verified my form builds and collects all its values correctly?

**app/config.yml**

```
#FOS UserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: propel # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: acme_user_registration

#Services
services:
    acme_user.registration.form.type:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: acme_user_registration }
    acme_user.form.handler.registration:
            class: Acme\UserBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler
            arguments: ["@fos_user.registration.form", "@request", "@fos_user.user_manager", "@fos_user.mailer", "@fos_user.util.token_generator"]
            scope: request
```

**app/routing.yml** is standard FOSUserBundle config as per docs

```
# FOSUserBundle Routing
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

**Acme/UserBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
    {
        return parent::render($view, $parameters, $response);
    }

}
```

**Acme/AdminBundle/Resources/views/_addUser.html.twig** this is where I call my modal in

```
{% include "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="registerUser" class="reveal-modal xlarge"  data-reveal>

    <h2 align="center">Add New User</h2>
    <h6 align="center" style="color: red">All Fields are Required</h6>

    {% block fos_user_content %}
        {% render url('fos_user_registration_register') %}
    {% endblock %}

    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>

</div>
```

**app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register.html.twig** Overidden as per docs

```
{% block fos_user_content %}
    {% include 'FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

**app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig** Overidden as per docs

```
<form data-abide class="fos_user_registration_register" action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="post" >
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Personal Details</legend>

                {# First Name #}
                <div>
                    <label for="form_first_name">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="form_first_name" name="form[first_name]" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"/>
                    <small class="error">This field is required</small>
                </div>

                {# Last Name #}
                <div>
                    <label for="form_last_name">Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" id="form_last_name" name="form[last_name]" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
                    <small class="error">This field is required</small>
                </div>

                etc...
                etc...
                etc...

            </fieldset>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The `RegistrationFormHandler` is injected with the `@request` service, but it might be better to inject this with `@request_stack` and then get the master request via `$request = $requestStack->getMasterRequest();`

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a little? So you mean change the acme_user.form.handler.registration service in app/config.yml to use @request_stack, but from where do you call getMasterRequest? From the overridden RegistrationFormHandler.php?

Comment: Abide appears to be working ok, as the fields get POSTed by the page according to the debuggers in both Safari and Chrome. Thank you for the input though :D

Comment: Do you extend FOSUB User class to one of your own bundle?

Comment: I have extended FOSUserBundle into my own AcmeUserBundle, and extended the FormType, FormHandler, and Controller using getParent() in my root AcmeUserBundle.php class

Answer (score 4):

You have to change your register_content.html.twig :

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register', 'id': 'register-form'} }) }}
{{ form_label(form.username) }}
{{ form_errors(form.username) }}        
{{ form_widget(form.username) }}
{{ form_label(form.email) }}
{{ form_errors(form.email) }}       
{{ form_widget(form.email) }}
{{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}
         {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
         {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}

         {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
         <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />

         {{ form_rest(form) }}
```

this works with me .You should see twig documentation about forms it will help you .

Comment: I have tried this method in its own view (ie. not modal) and it works the same as my existing overridden register_content.html.twig. My question is how to get this to work inside a modal view?

Comment: @Chris did you add this line
`{{ form_rest(form) }}` in your view?

Answer (score 1):

In the excerpt of `register_content`, the inclusion of `form_rest` function has not been explicitly introduced (There are `etc.` after the "surname" field).

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Calling this function takes care of adding required hidden fields like the one in charge of preventing `crsf` attacks.

Besides, not having included a call to `form_errors` prevents you from realizing if there are validation errors related to any fields (like the aforementioned `csrf` token if it were to be invalid for instance).

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

In order to clarify what could possibly be going wrong, you may want to access the logs generated by the form submission. For example, when relying on your (Symfony2) development environment:

```
tail -fn 100 app/logs/dev.log
```

You might find an error of some level telling you what the next stage of your problem solving session could be.

We could have a chat to live debug if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This does sound like a routing issue.  I overrode the FOSUser routes by not including them in my bundle.  Instead, I have my own route with the FOSUser name so that when the FOSUser form calls the FOSUser route, this route calls my custom controller.  In my MyUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml I have:

```
fos_user_registration_register:
    path:      /
    defaults:  { _controller: MyUserBundle:Register:register }
```

You can check what route and what controller is being called by going through a new registration process, then go to the click on the profiler bar, and look at the last 10 requests.  It will show what what route was matched and which controller was called.